# ¿Como crear un objeto request en laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Necesito tener un request en laravel 5.1, pero necesito crearlo desde php y no que me llegue desde un formulario..
Lo que estoy intentando es llamar una función de laravel para recuperar contraseñas de usuarios desde un controlador mio propio

```
private function sendEmailWithPassword($objUser)
{
//Se crea variable de request
Request $request;

//Se crea la propiedad email
$request->request->add(['email' => $objUser->Person->Email]);

//Se llama función de laravel
$this->PasswordController->postEmail($request);
}
```

He intentado crear un request de la siguiente manera

```
Request $request;
```

pero me aparece el siguiente error

```
syntax error, unexpected '$request' (T_VARIABLE)
```

En pocas palabras no me crea la variable, alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: ¿Puede añadir más contexto sobre su código? ¿donde está creando la variable? Tal y como está su pregunta no se puede reproducir su error.

Comment: Ya edito el codigo, lo que estoy intentando es llamar una función de laravel para reuperar contraseñas de usuarios

Comment: editado!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private function sendEmailWithPassword($objUser)
{
    //Se crea variable de request
    $requestObj = new Request(array('email' =>$objUser->Person->Email));

 //Se llama función de laravel
    $this->PasswordController->postEmail($requestObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No es la forma correcta de crear una variable de tipo `Request` , tal y como está su código `PHP` intenta buscar un tipo de dato `Request` para lo cuál no encuentra resultado y arroja el error.

Al ser una clase `Request`, debería crear una instancia y asignar a la variable.

```
private function sendEmailWithPassword($objUser)
{
    //Se crea variable de request
    $request = new Request();

    //Se crea la propiedad email
    $request->request->add(array('email' =>$objUser->Person->Email));

    //Se llama función de laravel
    $this->PasswordController->postEmail($request);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, callo como anillo al dedo esta respuesta!!!!